# Dropzone event for selection of multiple files

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I must to know when the user selects multiple files at once. The problem is Dropzone doesn't have an `addedmultiple` event.

**Background**

I want to animate individual files with a delay, so they appear one after another. For this I must to know how many files have been selected, so I can do something like:

```
dz.on('addedmultiple', function(files){
    files.forEach(function(file, index){
        var fileBox = $(file.previewElement).hide();

        setTimeout(function(){
            fileBox.fadeIn('fast');
        }, index * 100);
    });
});
```

I could add a global variable in conjunction with the `addedfile` event to count the files and then set a timeout to reset that variable. But this doesn't feel so good. Anyway, any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer just after asking hahaha.

Dropzone have an undocumented event called `selectedfiles`. So my approach ended something like this:

```
dz.on('selectedfiles', function(files){
    $(files).each(function(index){
        this.delay = index * 100;
    });
});

dz.on('addedfile', function(file){
    var fileBox = $(file.previewElement).hide();

    setTimeout(function(){
        fileBox.fadeIn('fast');
    }, file.delay);
});
```

Hope this help someone else with the same need.

Comment: I'm not sure which version were you using, but current version (as of 2017/01) has the "addedfiles" event, which does exactly what you need: it fires once per file selection on the file dialog (single or multiple).